# Javascript - web application structure

Tags: javascript, html, scope

I'm having issues managing data between the parts of my Javascript application. I'm trying to stick with a "MVC" pattern, so speaking in MVC terms, i can't make some of my "C" (controller) functions access the data given by "M" (model). Specifically i can't make event functions to reach the data without making the data global (which i want to try to avoid).

A made up situation just to show you what i mean:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div onclick="func()"></div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var Data = function(num) {
    this.num = num;
}

window.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var data = new Data(5);
}

function func() {
    //How do i access the object "data" from here?
}
```

The question is: how do i make the event handlers access the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var Data = function(num) {
    this.num = num;
}

var data;

window.onreadystatechange = function() {
    data = new Data(5);
}

function func() {
    //data.num
}
```

You have to declare data in a scope accessible to func

If you are worried about global variables you could do this

```
var service = {};

(function(service) {
    var Data = function(num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    var data;

    window.onreadystatechange = function() {
        data = new Data(5);
    }

    service.func = function func() {
        //data.num
    }
})(service);


//call the function
service.func();
```

This will call it in a self executing closure that will prevent the variables from entering global scope. You can pass in a service instance and attach the func method to it to be able to call it. Jquery plugins typically follow this pattern.

Comment: which is making it global, like he said :)

Comment: you need to expose func now

Comment: @KeithNicholas I agree. Added a solution to that

Comment: How do i assign the event handler to the object in that case then? Onclick=service.func() ?

Comment: You could even wrap service.func() in a function that you assign as your event handler